# Airflow Sensor in reschedule mode, does not trigger sla miss

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have a sensor under `reschedule` mode, and I also set a `sla` for this sensor. What I hope to happen is, if the sensor does not return success in 5 mins, it will be considered missing an sla and will send out an email. The problem is, currently it does not do anything. I'm guessing the problem is the sensor quickly turns to `up_for_reschedule` state thus was not considered missing an sla? How can I set/trigger `sla` for `sensor` under `reschedule` mode? Thanks a lot for your help.

```
dag = DAG(
       schedule_interval = "0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 * * * *",
       catch_up= False,
       default_args = {
           "start_date" :datetime(2021,06,12),
           "email" : "someemail@someplace.com"
       })
In sensor setting:
      sla = timedelta (minutes = 5)
      "poke_interval": 60*10
      "timeout" : 60*60*12
      "mode" : "reschedule"
```

Comment: Isn't SLA send only if the task last longer than schedule interval meaning that we have delay in data processing? I would leverage on_faliure_callback and timeout to send a message

Comment: @Tomasz Urbaszek  I thought SLA would be sent if a task is not finished by that time, according to the doc? For example in here `timedelta (minutes = 5)` SLA will be sent if Sensor does not return successful 5 minutes after scheduled time?

Comment: The thing is I don't want the sensor to timeout, but only want an email to be sent out. I hope the sensor keeps running.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it won't work as you expected. If I correctly understand the SLA is a time that can elapsed after next schedule run before we report an issue. It's mostly to report that things are getting out of schedule. It'a bit confusing part of Airflow

Comment: @TomaszUrbaszek Thanks! Could you elaborate a bit on that? So if a job is scheduled at 01:50 everyday like `50 01 * * * *` , and timeout is 12 hours as in 60*60*12,  the sla will be considered missed at 13:50 and email will only be sent out at that time(13:50)? and after timeout a job will fail?

Comment: In your case there will be SLA miss only if the task last longer than 13:50 next day. Simpler case: DAG runs every 10 minutes, SLA is 5 minutes, first run is at 1200, it runs till 1212 (no SLA miss), runs till 1216 (SLA miss by a minute) - that's my understanding

Comment: @TomaszUrbaszek Thanks a lot. What'd you suggest if I want to send an email or call some function after a customised time period? Say if I want to do something 3 hours after a job scheduled time. But I do not want the sensor task to fail. I'd like the sensor to keep running till the timeout (for example timeout is 12 hours).